# How to pass a NoneType error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently having an issue with my text adventure code, the program runs perfectly fine, but whenever the character winds up dying, the program calls this error:

```
    NextSceneName = CurrentScene.enter()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enter'
```

The program will crash after this, which is no big deal in itself.

The code for this part of the program is:

```
def play(self):
        CurrentScene = self.sceneMap.OpeningScene()
        LastScene = self.sceneMap.NextScene('Finished')

        while CurrentScene != LastScene:
            NextSceneName = CurrentScene.enter()
            CurrentScene = self.sceneMap.NextScene(NextSceneName)

        CurrentScene.enter()
```

What I want to know is, how do I use something like an If statement, or a Try Except statement to pass the NoneType/AttributeError?

Comment: from your code I can tell that if you use `if..else` block then it will always go to `else` and if you use `try..except` block flow control will always goes to except block, because you are trying to access method `enter()` which is not available for you class object `CurrentScene` may be you should specify what's that or have you actually got output on any test case? if you having problem getting output then post your desire output too.

Comment: Currently I have the desired output I need, as the text adventure is in working order, all I want to do is pass the error entirely so it doesn't show up when a death scene happens

Comment: oh! then use your statement in try block and action on failure in except block for statement where you have chances to get error.

Answer (score 0):

First, `CurrentScene` must be evaluated as `None`, that's why you're getting the error. The smart move would be to figure out why is that happening if that's not expected

But, if you want to catch that exception, replace your last line `CurrentScene.enter()` with this:

```
try:
    CurrentScene.enter()
except AttributeError:
    dosomething()
```

Or if you want to catch all that before you try to "enter", you can do this:

```
if CurrentScene == None:
    dosomething()
```

If that doesn't work it's probably because you are also calling `CurrentScene.enter()` from within the while loop, so do it there instead

Comment: what if he don't have any method enter() for CurrentScene ?

Comment: I've tried to place CurrentScene.enter() outside of the while loop. That only lead to a new error, a NameError, stating: "name 'CurrentScene' is not defined"

I'll have a crack at the if statement, see if that works